# Codenvy Debugging Environments for Python

Tags: python, debugging

I'm trying to use Codenvy for Python developments. However, it seems that they do not have an embedded debugging solution.

So I went to their help forum, and someone like me requested a debugger feature.

Here is their reply:

> Codenvy allows you to set up any debugging environment for any
>   language you need, exactly as you need it through a Dockerfile. Our
>   docs
>   [http://docs.codenvy.com/user/creating-custom-builder-runner-environments/#custom-overview]
>   outline how to set this up.
>
> If your current IDE provides sufficient debugging capabilities you can
>   now use it with Codenvy via our CLI. Documentation on our CLI is here:
>   [http://docs.codenvy.com/cli/]

However, I'm not sure what they meant by setting it through a docker file. I did find some hints

```
# Codenvy uses this port to map IDE clients to the debugger
# of your application within the Runner. Set these
# values to the port of your debugger and Codenvy will
# map this port to the debugger console in the browser.
# You can set this value multiple times.
# For example:
# ENV CODENVY_APP_PORT_8000_DEBUG 8000
#
# ENV CODENVY_APP_PORT_<port>_DEBUG <port>

# Set this value to the port of any terminals operating
# within your runner.  If you inherit a base image from
# codenvy/shellinabox (or any of our images that inherit
# from it, you do not need to set this value.  We already 
# set it for you.
# ENV CODENVY_WEB_SHELL_PORT <port>
```

Does this mean that I need to use an external IDE with the ports opened up in the docker container to debug? Can someone guide me through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try remote debugging, i.e. run the script in Codenvy and connect to with with a local IDE debugger. PyCharm has some nice tutorials on how to do it. Just make sure you use the right ports, i.e mapped ports.

Codenvy has no built in debugger for Python however, you can use use pdb.

Import it into your Python script, and then, instead of setting a breakpoint, just insert:

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I will try to use a remote debugger. However, I haven't got a chance to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I suspect, that part of your answer might be found here http://blog.codenvy.com/cooking-custom-build-environments/ otherwise you could email the author of http://thecli.blogspot.it/2014/12/diving-into-codenvy.html